# Does tor hide traffic from DNS servers?

Tags: anonymity, security, relays, dns

I am wondering if when using Tor my requests are hidden from my DNS servers.

For example, I have set up my computer to use google's IPv6 DNS servers, does google see the domains I am accessing?

I am sorry to have to ask such a seemingly basic question here, but I was really struggling to find a comprehensive answer through search engines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends, nowdays. A lot of people are using OpenDNS or Google DNS or other public DNS servers. For good - yes, but Tor routes DNS requests to the exit node to resolve, and sometimes a situation when you have the same open dns as the exit node is not rare. So the answer is - it hides your requests from your ISP DNS servers, but if you use open dns - there's a possibility that you will use the same open one as the exit node.

Comment: Does it matter if you are using the same one as the exit node? Your answer implies that the exit node's DNS servers are used, if this is the case then it wouldn't matter what DNS servers I have, as they can never know the request came from me

Comment: Correct. It will never be shown that request is originated from you. The exit node DNS and resolver is used all the time.